# Google Script to create an Excel Workbook from a Google Sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to run a Google Script that will scan through a list of Google Sheet's and create an Excel Spreadsheet copy of that Google Sheet...

Is that possible ?

I will have the Google Sheet's listed in a spreadsheet with the Google Sheet Reference.

Comment: I thought it was possible to convert a Google Spreadsheet to excel in code, since you can do it manually, but I'm not seeing anything in the documentation that allows that.